# How to determine the resolution of a raster with 0.25 degrees in meters?

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, resolution

I have a raster of 0.25 degrees resolution. What's the right equation to determine how is the resolution in meters?

Comment: There isn't one. The true distance varies by pixel in *both* dimensions.

Comment: so actually what I did is that the raster spatial reference is GCS-WGS-1984 and I projected it to WGS 1984 UTM Zone 11N spatial reference, this converted the cell size to meters but I don't know if this approach is right.

Comment: Okay, but there still isn't a 1:1 correspondence between degrees and UTM pixels. The interpolation is a factor in whether it's "right" (more specifically, how *not right* it is), but you have nowhere near enough information in the Question to determine that.

Comment: Okay, got it thank you. How about if the resolution is in arc seconds, is it the same?

Comment: There are lat/lon legth calculators in the web, for example http://www.csgnetwork.com/degreelenllavcalc.html.

Comment: @user30184 thank you.